# muddatagrid - make an hyperlink or a button

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

[This is the following link](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/jVNNj9owEL3nTzCyegiHhktvBES7ZSlVoSuRW1WtTDKi7jp2ZDvLsij_veNgUkBalhwSO35vPt48Pz4uuFCJ4a_a9Ca1FWoDq511WCZLdMk356rku9UqCmeLuvgiPTiZvvCykmiTr9zxZKELlDaaCPUXcweedycFKgd_umUUpUT38JkRBcwpiR2xyVRiSac2yfgTxp_6bBwBPemdlnWp7GF38geyEQscBvcCZTFiy7pco2GQCSeRtrQc3ERciY26FbvkJd6KfdBWOKFvjr3Qkv-vv91Bya3t-Omg0yMdnMg4jqJJTuLDHlpcZcQzdwjzqapLNHwtMQ3JxnCUGkagcAs_hHXdYdwfRiGCdjRDLEA_o6EUCNzuVA4Zt0_wU80VdcaleMXis_8f91vavmvzJAvfcnFqgWSG7t7o0luqJadnNYxjtsU1r8SgQiN0IXLnG2BUmg_cRE0vQJPc9s7cSupIqpokt5REET0fRmeIDF9c6-VkRae-Ae7h1LWiwdqK5_ievQ89VvVaihxySfM5NnshQYBYZ3wBM6Priga0QTcE61_NJVLQTTl65joyxPRmfD_k4V5c4DrgL6_Gg9Ekttv5gDGzJZeS9X-_kdVfl-tZC01fErJ18FXkvB29CL7MnaHRvVVpoHSGDOVketUuggXPZ-Afg642Cj6wva-8gY-w9302bNjBmqO1_gE) to try out the code

```cs
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(4)">
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Element" Field="Number" Title="Nr" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Sign" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Name" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Position" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code { 
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
{
    public class Element
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("small")]
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public double Molar { get; set; }
        public IList<int> Electrons { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
        }
    }
}
```

How to make an hyperlink or a button over the element Name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```cs
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(4)">
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Element" Field="Number" Title="Nr" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Sign" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Name">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudButton Size="@Size.Small" Variant="@Variant.Filled" Color="@Color.Primary" OnClick="@(() => this.Click(context.Item))">
                    @context.Item.Name
                </MudButton>
            </CellTemplate>
        </Column>
        <Column T="Element" Field="Position" />
        <Column T="Element" Field="Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code { 
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

    private void Click(Element element)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Clicked: {element.Name}");
    }
}
```